# BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint is not applied when configure httpBasic()

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

I already search here about problems with `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` but I'm not understand my actual problem. I am a app and I am protecting all endpoints with a basic authentication user/pass (`Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxx` header). But I need to make some custom exception when authentication fails, so I created my own entrypoint class to be able to incorporate my exception.

But this entry point only works when a **`httpBasic()`** is removed from `SecurityConfig` otherwise is skipped.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    ....

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthEntryPoint);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Component
    public class CustomBasicAuthEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
 
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public CustomBasicAuthEntryPoint(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }   
    
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        Error error = new Error();

        if (authException instanceof BadCredentialsException){
            error.setMessage("Unauthorized please add a basic auth");
            error.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            error.setTimestamp(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
        }
        else{
            error.setMessage(authException.getMessage());
            error.setStatusCode(response.getStatus());
            error.setTimestamp(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
        }

        response.setStatus(error.getStatusCode());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        objectMapper.writeValue(response.getWriter(), error);
    }    
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem changing the order of configuration

```java
 http
     .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
     .httpBasic()
        .and()
     .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthEntryPoint);
```

by

```java
 http
     .authorizeHttpRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
     .httpBasic()
         .authenticationEntryPoint(customBasicAuthEntryPoint)
         .and();
```

It makes sense.